# Objective-c Change view when iphone is horizontal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I know when the iphone is vertically or horizontlly? I want to switch views depending on the iphone orentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass, you can override one (or more) of these methods:

> - `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
> - `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
> - `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`
> - `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
> - `didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:`
> - `willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

From the documentation notes for [`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a):

> Subclasses may override this method to
>   perform additional actions immediately
>   prior to the rotation. For example,
>   you might use this method to disable
>   view interactions, stop media
>   playback, or temporarily turn off
>   expensive drawing or live updates. You
>   might also use it to swap the current
>   view for one that reflects the new
>   interface orientation. When this
>   method is called, the
>   interfaceOrientation property still
>   contains the view’s original
>   orientation.

Like so:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        // do a thing
    }

    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
             toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        // some other thing
    }
}
```